# How to pass ALL environment variables to container with docker exec

Tags: bash, docker

It's possible to set one or more environment variables in the container while doing `docker exec`, for example:

```
docker exec -ti -e VAR=1 -e HOME container_name command
```

But I would like to pass all the shell's environment variables without explicitly specifying them individually. Essentially the [equivalent](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html) of `sudo -E`, although it's a different thing.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/), there is no such option. But one hack would be something like:

```
env > env_vars && docker exec -ti --env-file ./env_vars container_name command
```

Which works, but I'm looking for a simple one step solution that doesn't involve creating a temporary file. Perhaps a bash trick I don't know or haven't thought of yet. Thanks.

**Please note**: Passing all environment variables is not recommended and defeats the purpose of container process isolation. This question is for knowledge, not about what should be done. Also, the question is specifically about running a temporary command in an existing container with `docker exec`, *not* about `docker run`.

Comment: Use that method. It's hard on purpose. Making it easy would mean people accidentally bake in all kinds of stuff into their containers they weren't expecting.

Comment: As you already said the documentation points out there is no in built way to pass your entire shells variables through to the container, this could expose all sorts of security issues or run time issues. Do you really have a need to pass EVERY env variable form your shell into the container. That seems super overkill or super lazy

Comment: I know what you mean. The variable names aren't known in advance. So long as one trusts the container and sees it as an extension of the shell, it's no different than running other processes that have access to the same shell and its environment.

Comment: A Docker container _isn't_ an extension of the shell, though.  By design a Docker container is isolated from the host filesystem and environment.  I wouldn't expect a debugging shell to carry over any of the environment from the containing host.

Comment: Agreed, I get all that. Thank you for emphasizing this for the benefit of the community, so it's clear that this is not recommended. However, I like to experiment and the answer can inspire other solutions. The point @ChrisDoyle made on "run time issues" is particularly important, IMHO, as local variables such as `$HOME` would be overridden. That said, I don't think that putting a process one normally runs on the shell in a container, makes it automatically less secure when it has access to the same environment. Also, the access is limited to `docker exec` not the main container process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Bash, using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) seems to work:

```
docker run --rm -ti --env-file <(env) alpine sh
```

Note, this creates a temporary fifo file behind the scenes anyway.

This will not work properly with variables containing new lines, they are cutoff on new lines. In this case, you should do something like this, I tried to make it short:

```
readarray -d '' -t args < <(env -0 | sed -z 's/^/--env\x00/')
docker run --rm -ti "${args[@]}" alpine sh
```

Comment: Yeah, same concept but this way looks better, only it doesn't seem to work with `docker exec`:  `open /dev/fd/63: no such file or directory`

Comment: Well, works on my system with docker 20.10.20 and archlinux.

Comment: Found out [why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279889/212177), `sudo` closes  the file descriptor created by [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). This works for me: `sudo su -c "docker exec --env-file <(env) container_name command"`. Thanks!

Comment: The nice thing about it is that this solution can easily be adapted to filter out only variables that are needed. For example, although the variable names in my case can't be known in advance, they do have a pattern. So one could easily do `--env-file <(env | grep pattern)` instead, to avoid passing everything.